# Double counting the number of proper divisors

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $n$ is a composite natural number.  Then $n$ has unique prime factorization.  To count the number of proper divisors, simply take the product of the exponents +1 in the prime factorization.

$$n = \prod_{i = 1}^{n} p_i^{a_i}$$

$$\mbox{proper divisors} = \prod_{i = 1}^{n}(a_i+1)$$

Is 1 counted multiple times by doing this?

For instance, I can choose from $a_0+1$ factors contributed from $p_0$, namely

$ 1, p_0, p_0^2, \dots , p_0^{a_0} $
Don't I count 1 multiple times?

Comment: Your notation is suspect because $n$ is used both as the left hand side and as the limit of the index.  Rarely does $n$ have $n$ distinct prime factors, if that is what you want to convey.

Comment: With this product you count *all* divisors, not only the proper ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't count 1 multiple times:

The divisor 1 is only obtained if you choose the exponent $0$ for every prime factor **at the same time** and the only way of doing that is by choosing every exponent to be $0$; there is only one way of doing it. Hence you do not double count $1$, nor any other divisor.

Answer (score 1):

In order to count one, the exponent on *each* prime factor has to be zero.  So you are only counting it once.

Answer (score 0):

As an example of how this works, consider the factors of $72 = 2^3\cdot 3^2$.

The factors are:

$$\begin {array}{c}
1 & 2 & 4 & 8 \\
3 & 6 & 12 & 24 \\
9 & 18 & 36 & 72
\end{array}$$

As you can see in this $(3{+}1)\times (2{+}1) $ array, $1$ only occurs once as the multiplication process produces another prime power factors otherwise.